# Javascript - array length outside of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know how can I use `array.length` outside of a function so I can work with that value elsewhere. I have this script:

```
var length = url_ytb.length; //returns 2

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {      
    if(event.data === 0) { 
        array_position++;
        player.loadVideoById(url_ytb[array_position]);
        length--;
    }
}

if (length == 0) {
  alert("Good");
}
```

My problem is that the alert won't happen. I have printed the length variable but it still returns 2 when it should return 0.

Comment: The if statement has already executed, it will not re-check with your code when `onPlayerStateChange()` is called

Comment: You have to check the length inside your onPlayerStateChange function or callback a function which will check then length from inside your onPlayerStatechange function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You can't as you are checking before the event itself. You have to check it when the event occurs. So it should be

```
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {      
    if(event.data === 0) { 
        array_position++;
        player.loadVideoById(url_ytb[array_position]);
        length--;
    }
   if (length == 0) {
     alert("Good");
   }
}
```